# Parse delimited flat file to doubly linked list of structs

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C program to read a file, tokenize the input into a doubly linked list, and do stuff with it, ie: sort it, walk it, write it ...etc

```
md@ubuntu:~/Documents/testproject$ cat test.txt
2017-07-25,14:50:02:477, 12104,932,HOST, log message 1111111111111111111111111111
2017-07-26,14:50:02:478, 12104,932,HOST, log message 22222222222222222222222222222222222222
2017-07-27,14:50:03:095, 12104,932,HOST, log message 3333333333333333
2017-07-28,14:50:04:587, 12104,932,HOST, log message 444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
2017-07-29,14:50:04:587, 12104,932,HOST, log message blah blah blahb 1234455e56456546 test test test ERrroRRRrrr$$4RRrr
junk to be parsed out
more junk 1234567
```

However when I walk the list each node contains the last entry. Any suggests on where I'm going wrong here ? I've added `printf` in the `createnewnode()` function, and it seem that the correct strings are being set in the struct node.

```
md@ubuntu:~/Documents/testproject$ ./doubly test.txt
*****CREATE NODE*****(2017-07-25,14:50:02:477,932,HOST, log message 1111111111111111111111111111
*****CREATE NODE*****(2017-07-26,14:50:02:478,932,HOST, log message 22222222222222222222222222222222222222
*****CREATE NODE*****(2017-07-27,14:50:03:095,932,HOST, log message 3333333333333333
*****CREATE NODE*****(2017-07-28,14:50:04:587,932,HOST, log message 444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
*****CREATE NODE*****(2017-07-29,14:50:04:587,932,HOST, log message blah blah blahb 1234455e56456546 test test test ERrroRRRrrr$$4RRrr

*****PRINT LINKED LIST*****
0x557237b1a760 1986300429 2017-07-29 14:50:04:587 932,HOST, log message blah blah blahb 1234455e56456546 test test test ERrroRRRrrr$$4RRrr
0x557237b1a720 1986300429 2017-07-29 14:50:04:587 932,HOST, log message blah blah blahb 1234455e56456546 test test test ERrroRRRrrr$$4RRrr
0x557237b1a6e0 1986300429 2017-07-29 14:50:04:587 932,HOST, log message blah blah blahb 1234455e56456546 test test test ERrroRRRrrr$$4RRrr
0x557237b1a6a0 1986300429 2017-07-29 14:50:04:587 932,HOST, log message blah blah blahb 1234455e56456546 test test test ERrroRRRrrr$$4RRrr
0x557237b1a250 1986300429 2017-07-29 14:50:04:587 932,HOST, log message blah blah blahb 1234455e56456546 test test test ERrroRRRrrr$$4RRrr
```

Code:

```
/*
Parse a delimited log file and tokenized values in a doubly linked list. 
Do stuff with this doubly linked list of structures (ie: sort by time....etc)

*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <locale.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define __USE_XOPEN
#include <time.h> 
#include <sys/time.h>

#define LINESIZE 1024

//Linked List structure
struct node
{
    int jobid;   
    char* datestring;
    char* timestring;
    char* message;
    struct node *prev;  //previous node
    struct node *next; //next node 
};
typedef struct node node;

node *head = NULL;  //declar pointer beginning of linked list

//prototypes for linked list functions   
struct node* createnewnode(char* ds, char* ts, char* msg); //create a new node and return a pointer to it
void insert_at_head(char* ds, char* ts, char* msg);
void print_elements(); 
static void clean(); 
int parseFile(char* fname);
char **strsplit(const char* str, const char* delim, size_t* numtokens);
int lensum(char **input);


/* DOUBLY LINKED LISTS */


//Node Generator 
struct node* createnewnode(char* ds, char* ts, char* msg)
{
    node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));  //allocate memory on the heap and create a new node structure 

    //copy strings to local variables. Desperate hope to get this working, but probably not needed
    char tds[LINESIZE], tts[LINESIZE],tmsg[LINESIZE];

    strcpy(tds, ds); 
    strcpy(tts, ts); 
    strcpy(tmsg, msg); 

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("*****CREATE NODE*****(%s,%s,%s\n",tds,tts,tmsg);
#endif  


    newnode->datestring = tds;
    newnode->timestring = tts;
    newnode->message = tmsg;

    srand(time(NULL));
    newnode->jobid = rand(); //set to random value to see if it changes between iterations

    newnode->prev = NULL;    
    newnode->next = NULL;   

    return newnode;
}


//Insert Node at the beginning of the list
void insert_at_head(char* ds, char* ts, char* msg)
{ 

    node *newnode = createnewnode(ds, ts, msg);

    //If this is the first element being added to the linked list 
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
        return;
    }
    head->prev = newnode;
    newnode->next = head;
    head = newnode; 
}

//print_elements() in linked list from the head to the tail (end)
void print_elements() 
{
    node *ptmp = head; //beginning of the list 
    if (ptmp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Warning: No elements in this list\n");
        return;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\n*****PRINT LINKED LIST*****\n");
#endif

    while(ptmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%p %d %s %s %s\n",ptmp, ptmp->jobid, ptmp->datestring, ptmp->timestring, ptmp->message );
        ptmp = ptmp->next; 
    }
    return; 
}


static void clean() 
{
    node *temp = NULL; 

    while(head != NULL) 
    {
        temp = head; 
        head = head->next; 
        free(temp);
    }
}



/* PARSE FILE */
int parseFile(char* fname)
{
    FILE *in = fopen(fname, "r");
    char line[LINESIZE];
    struct tm date;
    const char delim[] = ",";
    char *tok; 
    char dbuf[LINESIZE], tbuf[LINESIZE], mbuf[LINESIZE]; 

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), in) != NULL) {


     if ((void *)strptime(line,"%Y-%m-%d",&date) != NULL)
       {
           tok = strtok(line, delim);
           strcpy((char*)dbuf, tok);

           tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
           if (NULL != tok)
           {
                strcpy((char*)tbuf, tok);
                tok = strtok(NULL,delim);
           }
           tok = strtok(NULL,"\n"); 

           if (NULL != tok)
           {
                strcpy((char*)mbuf, tok);
           }

           insert_at_head(dbuf, tbuf, mbuf);

       }  

    }
    fclose(in); //close file pointer
    return 0;   
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    parseFile("test.txt"); 
    print_elements();   
    clean();         

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies in the function `struct node* createnewnode(char* ds, char* ts, char* msg)` The memory you allocate with at the line

```
char tds[LINESIZE], tts[LINESIZE],tmsg[LINESIZE];
```

is local to the function. It disappears when you leave the function, so the later lines

```
    newnode->datestring = tds;
    newnode->timestring = tts;
    newnode->message = tmsg;
```

will not do what you intended.

You can do reserve some memory on the heap, e.g.:

```
    //char tds[LINESIZE], tts[LINESIZE],tmsg[LINESIZE];

    char *tds = malloc(LINESIZE); // can be fixed if length is fixed
    char *tts = malloc(LINESIZE); // can be fixed if length is fixed
    char *tmsg = malloc(LINESIZE); // the message is probably variable, so measure it
```

but you have to free that memory later.

Or reserve some stack memory by changing the `struct` e.g.:

```
struct node
{
   int jobid;   
   char datestring[100];
   char timestring[100];
   char message[256];
   struct node *prev;   //previous node
   struct node *next; //next node 
};
```

but that enlarges the `struct` by a non-insignificant amount and is less flexible. The message, for example, might need more than 256 characters.

Or use a mixed approach and use the stack for the date and timestring if they are always of the same fixed length and the heap for the message by measuring the length of the entry in the file and allocate memory accordingly. Don't forget to free the heap-memory when cleaning up!

Comment: Thanks for your help, as you can see i'm a C noob.  I used solution #1 and it's working correctly now.